# Extend Ember RESTAdapter to work with CouchDB

Tags: ember.js, couchdb, ember-data

I am using CouchDB for basically my entire back-end, and Ember for basically my entire front-end, and I need to find a way to make the json data compatible between the two, especially regarding the 'named root' convention (here are the [ember json expectations](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/) and the [couch api](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/api.html)). I'm not using Ruby or any other libraries, so I'm quite sure [this couch adapter](https://github.com/pangratz/ember-couchdb-adapter) isn't available to me.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429426/ember-js-rest-adapter-without-json-root) that I'll need to extend the `extract` method to get this to work properly, but I'm freaked out by this whole thing and am not sure where to start. What's the relationship between `RESTAdapter` and `JSONSerializer`? I'm not sure how this all fits together and I'm terrified of wasting time and possibly screwing something up. And is there maybe an easier way to do this?

Forgive my noobiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a CouchDB adapter that does seem to be up to date (last updated 2 days ago), at https://github.com/roundscope/ember-couchdb-kit. As it says, "Inspired by [pangratz/ember-couchdb-adapter](https://github.com/pangratz/ember-couchdb-adapter) and contains many fixes and newbie features."

While the installation is easy within a Rails project, it's still fine outside of a Rails project. Just include everything from the `dist` directory in this order:

- ember-couchdb-kit
- registry
- document-adapter
- attachment-adapter
- revs-adapter
- changes-feed

Comment: Excellent! It says I should learn the interface through the specs using `rake`, but, you know, I don't have that, so I'd love to know how to get at the specs without doing that?

Comment: Also, it seems to imply with this line: `open -a safari http://localhost:8888` that `rake jasmine` will run the spec docs on a local server? Frankly, that sounds annoying hahaha I'm running a local testing server and I'd prefer not to have my `apache` instance messed with.

Comment: I figured out my last comment (I feel a little dumb for it), but now all of the specs are failing. Any advice? I've formally asked a [question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665625/ember-couchdb-kit-fails-all-jasmine-specs).

Answer (score 1):

> I read here that I'll need to extend the extract method to get this to work properly

The SO post (and the couch adapter) you referenced are out-of-date. Ember Data changed a lot in the past few weeks, so lots of the old answers out there could be misleading.

> I'm freaked out by this whole thing and am not sure where to start.

The good news is it's become somewhat easier to do the kind of thing you are trying. While writing a custom adapter and serializer used to be an advanced topic it is now really straightforward.

At present the best resources are:

- [the guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/)
- [the ember-data transition doc](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)
- [discussion on migrating to the beta](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/migrating-from-ember-data-0-13-to-1-0-0-beta-1-my-findings/2368)

> What's the relationship between RESTAdapter and JSONSerializer?

An adapter is an object that receives requests from a store and translates them into the appropriate action to take against your persistence layer. The RESTAdapter is an adapter that knows how to talk to a *restful* HTTP server by transmitting JSON via XHR.

A serializer is responsible for serializing and deserializing a group of records. The JSONSerializer is just a serializer that knows how to read and write JSON.

With new ember-data it should be pretty straightforward to extend/configure the rest-adapter and json serializer to speak to a CouchDB backend. Have a look at [rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration) for some examples.

Comment: An excellent response. Sorry it took me so long to recognize it! This project has had lots of distractions...

Comment: Well, the other answer ended up being the better choice for me. I was trying to do the adapter myself, and I just realized I was letting "not invented here" to get to me, so I've ditched it and am going with that.

Comment: Good call. I'd not heard of the other CouchDB adapter but at first glance it looks pretty solid.