# ember-couchdb-kit fails all Jasmine specs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, couchdb, jasmine

I'm trying to use the [`ember-couchdb-kit` adapter built by roundscope](https://github.com/roundscope/ember-couchdb-kit), but it's not working as expected.

When I follow the instruction to `rake jasmine`, it fails all 20 specs, all with the same error,

`timeout: timed out after 3000 msec waiting for model should be saved`

(or something closely related to that)

Also, my `couchdb` terminal shows errors *like* this:

```
[info] [<0.171.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - OPTIONS /doc 404
```

Here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ePFyWrtY) for every output given by `couchdb` after the spec is run.

I've set this all up just as a `js` directory as specified in the docs:

> An ember-couchdb-kit ships both with compiled js assets and coffee sources. Compiled assets plased in dist/**.js folder.

and suggested to me in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687870/extend-ember-restadapter-to-work-with-couchdb/19150334#19150334)

Any advice? Have I not configured things properly?

**Edit**. I created a `doc` database, and then half of the log errors went away, the ones saying `doc.couch` didn't exist, but everything else remained the same.