# Delete JSON root element for POST/PUT operations in Ember Data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm consuming a web service that in POST/PUT verbs expects a JSON like this:

```
{
    "id":"CACTU",
    "companyName": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
    "contactName": "Patricio Simpson",
    "contactTitle": "Sales Agent",
    "address": "Cerrito 333",
    "city": "Buenos Aires",
    "postalCode": "1010",
    "country": "Argentina",
    "phone": "(1) 135-5555",
    "fax": "(1) 135-4892"
}
```

But Ember Data sends a JSON like this:

```
{
    "customer": 
    {
        "id":"CACTU",
        "companyName": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
        "contactName": "Patricio Simpson",
        "contactTitle": "Sales Agent",
        "address": "Cerrito 333",
        "city": "Buenos Aires",
        "postalCode": "1010",
        "country": "Argentina",
        "phone": "(1) 135-5555",
        "fax": "(1) 135-4892"
    }
}
```

How I can delete "customer" root element when sending POST/PUT operations?

Comment: look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429426/ember-js-rest-adapter-without-json-root

Comment: @melc seems to refer only to GET requests

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll want to override one of the serialize methods, I think serializeIntoHash might work:

```
App.CustomerSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(record, options));
  }
});
```

This is instead of the normal serializeIntoHash which looks like this:

```
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    hash[type.typeKey] = this.serialize(record, options);
  }
```

Additional documentation can be found here:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.1.0/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest-serializer.js#L595

Comment: it's so easy that I'm ashamed. Thank you very much

Comment: Ummm...  not so much for me...  I did the exact same thing in my serializer, but the result of calling _super() is an object that is already flattened, without a root node.  I'm afraid this technique does not work.

Comment: I didn't actually test it out Steve, but it should have been around there, it might actually be the serializeIntoHash method instead of the serialize method, see above.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @kingpin2k ...  I added 'serializeIntoHash' exactly as you have given along with a log to the console, and I found that serializeIntoHash was not being called.  I don't understand how this is working for Merrin.

Comment: @SteveH. would you create a jsbin, or explain in more detail what exactly you're doing?

Comment: @kingpin2k Got it- serializeIntoHash as you have given is doing the trick- I had other problems but now working... Thanks!