# EmberJS deserialize json in c#

Tags: c#, json, ember.js, json.net, ember-data

I am using ember-data and the RESTSerializer to output my model data.
I originally wanted it to output JSONAPI format because it would have been so simple to convert it on the server side using C# as there is a JSONAPI.Net library that uses the type information to convert it to the correct object. However, it does not look like it is properly implemented for embedded objects when posting data from ember. So now I am using the RESTSerializer and my JSON looks like so:

```
{
    "labelProject":{
        "id":"0f261196-c46e-442f-a6a7-cbc6aeae3336",
        "name":"Project",
        "labelGroups":[
            {
            "id":"71d99d43-fa65-4233-ae80-d5a136edb7d2",
            "name":"Group1",
            "labelType":"Type1"

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a nice way to get this into DTO objects in C# using NewtonSoft JSON without having to write a bunch of different converters (my JSON string contains more nested objects) like I can do with JSONAPINet.

With JSONAPINet I can just put a `[JsonApiResourceType("label-groups")]` attribute on the DTO and it will know how to convert it if the label-groups type property is supplied.

Comment: did you tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>("JSON")` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the root keys of the objects before I could use JsonConvert.Deserialize. [Delete JSON root element for POST/PUT operations in Ember Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571025/delete-json-root-element-for-post-put-operations-in-ember-data)