# Ember.js REST Adapter use JSON root(use ember-data)

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

The Ember.js REST Adapter expects the JSON to be returned as:

```
{
    "customer": {
         "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
        "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
        "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
        "id": "b0d16ed0-c901-4ca3-ba41-7fc74c96909f"
   }
}
```

But my API returns the data without a root element:

```
{
        "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
        "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
        "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
        "id": "b0d16ed0-c901-4ca3-ba41-7fc74c96909f"
}
```

I find a question here: [Ember.js REST Adapter without JSON root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429426/ember-js-rest-adapter-without-json-root), but the answers is too old, don't works
in the newest version of ember and ember-data.

Sorry for my poor English, hope that's clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `serializeIntoHash` in the serializer:

```
serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
    Ember.merge(data, this.serialize(record, options));
}
```

For your second question, look at `typeForRoot`. Why not just read the entire page on adapters?

Comment: If you have another question, then ask another question. SO question are not like serial novels, where you add one new sub-question per day.

Comment: OK. I'll remove it and ask another question