# Ember.js error: You must include an 'id' for an object passed to 'push'

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

The REST API which I am using to fetch data doesn't give proper JSON as expected by Ember.js. We don't have id values in our data.

```
[{"objectID":"340907","owner":"Lokesh"},{"objectID":"340908","owner":"Cherukuri"}]
```

So, I created a a serializer:

**serializers/baddata.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'objectID'
});
```

**adapters/baddata.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8080',
    buildURL : function(modelName, id) {
        return this.host + "/baddata/trains/"+ id;
    }
});
```

**models/baddata.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    owner: DS.attr('string')
});
```

This did not solve the problem. Can someone correct my mistakes?

Comment: Once you have mapped the ID in your serializer using `primaryKey`, it is now called `id`, so you don't need to declare `objectID` in your model, and you should refer to the relevant field everywhere in your code as `id`. `push` should then work fine. It will get mapped back to `primaryKey` on the way up to the server.

Comment: No. it didn't work. same error

Comment: Which serializer(json, jsonapi, rest) are you using and is that the full response you get from the API?

Comment: i am using JSONSerializer. yes it is full reponse

Answer (score 1):

I am using mongo and in your example I see that you have used ApplicationSerializer. I think that you need to use following

If you use JSONSerializer then

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'objectID'
});
```

If you use REST Serializer

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS. RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'objectID'
});
```

I tried to search ApplicationSerializer class but it is not mentioned under doc. This is what works for me and mongo which I use to change to _id

Hope it helps

Comment: When i changed it to JSONSerializer, same error occurred. But when i changed to RESTSerializer, New Error: Cannot read property '_internalModel' of null. Is that serializer expecting my response to have a root element?

Comment: Your endpoint on server side how does it send data? If you use ActiveModelSerializer or RESTSerializer then root is expected. Here is related post where you can override it to  exclude root: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429426/ember-js-rest-adapter-without-json-root

Comment: I changed to JSONSerializer. But that did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `DS.RESTSerializer` and override `normalizeResponse` to turn your data into:

```
{ baddata: { "id":"340907", "owner":"Lokesh" } }
```

Converting `objectID` into `id` will just make your life easier. You might as well, since you already need to override `normalizeResponse` to format the payload.

This assumes you are fetching a single record at a time. If you fetch multiple records, you'll want

```
{
  baddatas: [
    { "id":"340907", "owner":"Lokesh" },
    { "id":"340908","owner":"Cherukuri" }
  ]
}
```

See [DS.RESTSerializer#normalizeResponse](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeResponse)

Comment: If this is the case, then what is the point of setting primary key on the serializer, and why don't the docs reflect this?